# VBA checking for value (shell-ID) from Sheet1 and Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

**VBA checking for value (shell-ID) from Sheet1 and Sheet2.**

So, I am a complete beginner to VBA. Yet, I have been trying to figure out the code for this using various internet sources. So my idea for this is that i have two sheets of data (say sheet1 and sheet2). Sheet1 is the master list and sheet2 has all the major data. Now, my main conditions are that if the Shell-ID of a specific row in sheet1 matches the Shell-ID in sheet2, then just update the phase of the project. But if the value does not exist, then copy other columns like name of the project, project description, phase of the project etc. for that corresponding shell-ID back into sheet1 from sheet2.

So far, I can only make the entire row copied onto the sheet but not specific parts that I require. Here is my code and what I have tried. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** for some reason I cannot attach files to stack (dont know if its possible to be honest) but I have added the pictures for the sheet

```
Sub Copying()
'defining the variables

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, fn As Range, sr As Range, rng As Range, n As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set sh1 = Sheet1
Set sh2 = Sheet2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'counting the number of rows in sheet 1

 With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  End With

  'gives you the number of rows
 MsgBox ("Sheet1 has " & lr & "rows")

   'counting rows for sheet2
 With Worksheets("Sheet2")
j = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

'gives the number of rows for sheet2 
 MsgBox ("Sheet2 has " & j & "rows")

'checking the value from sheet2 vs sheet1 for shell ID #, if not present then it will copy the entire row


For i = 2 To j


    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> 
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        .Rows(i).Copy 

     Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lr)

        lr = lr + 1

        ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).Value = 
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then

    End If

    End With

    Next i

      MsgBox ("Copying complete")

 End Sub
```

[image: sheet1]
[image: sheet2]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60226315/edit) your question and post some sample data. Explain how do you decide which parts of the sheet it should copy

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I have made the edits. Let me know if the description is still unclear! Thanks